# core date update

Tags: swift, core-data

I am stacked in updating core date. I understand that I need to fetch but I don't know how. In my code, new records come, but not update.

**Code:**

```
@IBAction func saveBtm(sender: AnyObject) {

    do {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: self.context)
        fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
        let result = try self.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", nameDataPassed)
        if (result.count > 0) {
            let person = result[0] as! NSManagedObject 
            person.setValue(nameText.text, forKey: "name")
            person.setValue(surnameText.text, forKey: "surname")
```

Comment: You aren't executing the fetch... Why not?

Comment: Thanks, I did it but, then I try to edit another record program still edit the last fetched, can you help solve this.

Comment: please add code to the question not comments, it can't be read in the comments

Comment: How do I understand I neet to fetch needed me records

Comment: I'd suggest you need to use a predicate to find the exact existing object

Comment: I found couple examples but it not working, could you please help

Comment: How do you determine that something is a duplicate? By the name and surname? By a unique id?